# Eliminating unwanted rows from mysql result

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL result (obtained by joining three tables) which looks like this:

```
  article_id |  article_name  | tag_id |    tag      | article_ref |  tag_ref
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    00021    |   Red jumper   |   14   | fisherman   |    00021    |    14
    00023    | Fishermans knit|   13   |  batwing    |    00023    |    13       
    00023    | Fishermans knit|   14   | fisherman   |    00023    |    14  
    00023    | Fishermans knit|   15   | rollneck    |    00023    |    15    
    00025    | Green Guernsey |   14   | fisherman   |    00025    |    14
```

(the search being %fisherman%)
I have obtained this by searching for %like% results and comparing two tables - the article table and the tag table (with a relational table tagsrel).

I would like to eliminate extraneous rows of the same article_id (see first column).
I am looking into doing this with

`SELECT FROM 
   (SELECT FROM /*original query */)`

with perhaps a `DISTINCT`? although the rows are not unique, as you can see. Ideally I would like to just select the first with that id. so my results would be:

```
  article_id |  article_name  | tag_id |    tag     | article_ref |  tag_ref
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    00021    |   Red jumper   |   14   | fisherman  |    00021    |    14
    00023    | Fishermans knit|   13   |  batwing   |    00023    |    13       
    00025    | Green Guernsey |   14   | fisherman  |    00025    |    14
```

My question really is can I apply (as above) another SELECT to this to eliminate said rows?
Thanks in advance (I have been stuck on this for days now!!!)

---

SOLUTION: As per Juan Carlos Oropeza's answer below, with the alias added for inserting the query

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *,
              @rn := if(@article = `article_id`,
                        @rn + 1,
                        if(@article := `article_id`, 1, 1)
                       ) as rn
       FROM (/*query*/) AS bob
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @article := '' ) as T
       ORDER BY `article_id`, tag_id 
     ) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY  `article_id`
```

Comment: why you have selected tag_id 13 for Fishermans knit ?

Comment: So, the join is causing these results to appear with the different tag_ID, tag and tag_rel.... if you don't need those fields... why include them on the join or select?  or you could use group_concat() to combine all the values for those records... or better... perhaps you need two separate queries.  one for just the articles and another for the details?

Comment: oh the search is %fisherman%, I should have said that!

Comment: @xQbert, I do need them, I am after the article_id, and it joins the tag table I just need to strip out the additional article_ids

Comment: So then don't include tag_Id, tag, tar_rel_Id if you just need article_ref only return it in the select along with the article_ID and article_name and then use distinct...  I'd need to see select and desired results at this point, as I think the problem is you're returning more data than you need in your results; which is causing the duplication

Comment: @xQbert, I need one query so I can limit and offset them and have them all in one set of results

Comment: as @knowledge.... said. Why you select `tag_id = 13` for `article = 00023` and not the others? What is the logic?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza " Ideally I would like to just select the first with that id"

Comment: @xQbert ok, but what tell you who is the first? what order you use? `tag_id` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use variables to select the first one of each `article_id`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LQPC95092)**

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *,
              @rn := if(@article = `article_id`,
                        @rn + 1,
                        if(@article := `article_id`, 1, 1)
                       ) as rn
       FROM yourTable
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @article := '' ) as T
       ORDER BY `article_id`, tag_id 
     ) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY  `article_id`
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

ADITIONAL TIP:

```
SELECT bda_articles.article_name,bda_articles.article_id, bda_tags.*, bda_tagsrel.*
FROM bda_articles 
JOIN bda_tagsrel
    ON bda_articles.article_id = bda_tagsrel.article_ref                    
JOIN bda_tags
    ON bda_tagsrel.tag_ref=bda_tags.tag_id          
WHERE (`article_name` LIKE "%fisherman%"
   OR `tag` LIKE "%fisherman%")
  AND tag_ref  = (SELECT MIN(tag_ref) 
                  FROM bda_tagsrel TAG
                  WHERE TAG.article_ref = bda_articles.article_id)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this, but where in this do I put my original query?

Comment: Check the demo. Your original query go instead of `YourTable` as you can see I use your data to create that table.

Comment: This is looking interesting, I will try this - it may take me a while as my MySQL is basic. I am surprised though that there isn't a simple function to only select one of a row with a particular value

Comment: In other DB you have `ROW_NUMBER()` to do the same without variables. But MySQL is still in the caves. That is why Postgres as free DB is much better.

Comment: oh, that is interesting! For the moment I am stuck with MYSQL though!!

Comment: fyi I have added above the original query and the tables it selects, in case you think I am selecting too much data

Comment: Check my edit. You can filter the query to only include the first tag.

Comment: THIS NEARLY works. BUT: When I change the search term from fisherman to something else I am still getting fisherman results? How come?

Comment: Update the SQL DEMO with more data and the query you are trying then send me the link so I can see the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am running SELECT * FROM (/*my orig query*/) AS yourTable; then your code. I get fisherman results no matter what, strangely

Comment: Nop... you should use  `Myquery  FROM ((/*my orig query*/) AS yourTable;`

Comment: But again, if you build a working demo in rextester I can help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143412/discussion-between-gavin-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: The above code works when querying a table. But replacing FROM yourTable with FROM (/*original query*/) results with the error #1248 every derived table must have its own alias. Can someone supply me with the correct syntax please?

Comment: after your close your sub query you need add an alias. like this `FROM ( /* query */) as anotherAlias`

Comment: I tried that before. I went away and had a cup of tea and tried it again. HOLY COW IT WORKS!!!!!!!!! (I still don't believe it) Thanks for all your help. I will update above, test it a bit and uptick the answer